# Help evaluating $\int _0^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-\lambda x}}{xe^x}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, parametric

I need help evaluating $$F(\lambda) = \int _0^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-\lambda x}}{xe^x}dx$$ $\lambda \gt 1$

I know that I should use the derivate under the sign of the integral but I'm having trouble how to show that this function holds the properties to do so.

To be able to use the derivate under the integral the function $F(\lambda)= \int _0^{+\infty} f(x,\lambda)dx$ should hold these properties

$1.$ The function $f(x,\lambda)$ and it's partial derivative $f'_\lambda$ should be continous for $0 \le x \lt +\infty$ and $\lambda \gt -1$

For this to be true  I took $$f(x, \lambda)= \begin{cases} \frac{1-e^{-\lambda x}}{xe^x} ,  & x \neq0 \\[2ex]
 \lambda & x = 0 \end{cases}$$

$2.$ The integral $ \int _0^{+\infty} f(x,\lambda)dx$ is convergent for $\lambda \gt -1$

$3.$ The integral  $ \int _0^{+\infty} f'_\lambda(x,\lambda)dx$ should be uniformly convergent for $\lambda \gt -1$

The second point is where I'm having trouble because I don't know how to prove that the integral converges

Comment: Isn't this just $\ln(\lambda+1)$?

Comment: @Jam: unclear what you call "this". The OP is trying to check if the conditions of application of integration under the integral sign are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The integrand is bounded in $[0,1]$, hence you can consider convergence of

$$\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-x}}xdx-\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{(-1-\lambda)x}}xdx.$$

> $$\int_1^\infty\dfrac{e^{-ax}}xdx<\int_1^\infty e^{-ax}dx=\frac{e^{-a}}a.$$

Comment: Thank you for this but how do I show that the integral is bounded in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @J.Dane: how could it not be ?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the integral directly as follows using [Fubini-Tonelli (FT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function)

\begin{eqnarray*} \int _0^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-\lambda x}}{xe^x}dx
& = & \int _{x=0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\int_{y=0}^{\lambda}e^{-yx}\;dy\;dx \\
& \stackrel{FT}{=} & \int_{y=0}^{\lambda}\int_{x=0}^{+\infty}e^{-(1+y)x}\;dx\;dy \\
& = & \int_{y=0}^{\lambda} \frac{1}{1+y}\; dy \\
& = & \ln(1+\lambda)
\end{eqnarray*}

Note, that $e^{-(1+y)x}$ is **non-negative and measurable** on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,\lambda]$. So, according to Fubini-Tonelli the order of integration can be exchanged without changing the value of the integral (see the link above).

Comment: This is useless as long as you have not proven the validity. It does not answer the question.

Comment: To see that it is valid and, hence, useful one can quickly refer to the link I provided.

Comment: Then you need to show that Fubini's conditions of validity are fulfilled. And the question is about point 2. of the OP.

Comment: Maybe you did not specify enough what triggers you here. My intention here is to show another way how to evaluate the given integral. I was fully aware that the OP was ALSO asking about a justification for the differentiation under the integral. But the OP also asked generally for help to evaluate the integral.

Comment: I changed my previous comment.

Comment: My anchor point here is where the OP says "I know that I should use the derivate under the sign of the integral ...". IMO it is a valid (and hopefully useful) answer if one shows also another way (which happens here on MSE many many times). At least in the question there is no exclusion of certain methods or any demand for a specific method. I will add a line referring to the interchange order of integration.